# mapbox - querySourceFeatures returns several arrays and the first ones are sometime blank with filter

Tags: mapbox

I load my mapbox map as follows;

```
map.on('load', (e) => {    
   
    map.addSource('aa_winter_spoorts_points', {
        type: 'vector',
        url: 'mapbox://username.3t9kz8q5' 
    });
     
    map.addLayer({
        'id': 'aa_winter_spoorts_points',
        'type': 'symbol',  
        'source': 'aa_winter_spoorts_points',
        'source-layer': 'aa_winter_sports_points-6lir92',
        'layout': {
            'visibility': 'visible',
            'icon-image': 'mountain-11',
            'icon-allow-overlap': true
        },
    });
    
    map.on("sourcedata", function(e) {
        if (map.getSource('aa_winter_spoorts_points') && map.isSourceLoaded('aa_winter_spoorts_points')) {
            //console.log('source loaded!');
            // Find all features in one source layer in a vector source
            let features = map.querySourceFeatures('aa_winter_spoorts_points', {
                sourceLayer: 'aa_winter_sports_points-6lir92',
                filter: ["==", "id", "way/771665618"]
            });
            console.log(features);
            
            
        }
        
    });    
});
```

The above results in several lines of output.  The first lines are array(0) and then a bunch of lines of [rd]/array but when I open them up they are all 0 (meaning only one array in this case) and then the data of way/771665618 but several lines.  I was expecting only one record, 0, and it to hold data of  way/771665618.

Any help appreciated.